# Print line entry from a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, flow, powerapp, template

New to the sharepoint and power platform setup and wanted some advice.
I have setup a simple payment request generator in powerapps and power automate where the data and its approval status gets stored in a sharepoint list. 
What would be the best way to print the data from each line item into a pre-formatted document? Would a html file be the easiert  way or something else.
 
I am quite new to the whole concept so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you can use the action populate a word template to do so. Here is a tutorial about creating a simple word file with a template and send it in an Email.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zzm965PlYl0

Note: The actions with word needs premium

As for SharePoint list, you can use triggers like `When an item is created` to trigger the flow when a new item is created or `For a selected item` to do it manually. Then you can use the dynamic content to fill list item filed values to the word file.

Comment: I have tried the word template but the drawback here was that it was a premium connector. One alternative that I considered was to connect to the sharepoint list in excel and then vlookup the fields. However I was hoping to have something that could be triggered directly from the SP list.